# Fetch the data but unable to display data in html using Angularjs spring

Tags: html, angularjs, spring, frontend

Actually, Fetch the data but unable to visible in HTML code. In the web browser console displays the json data. but not visible in HTML code. this is my angular js code

```
$scope.refresh = function(){
    fetchData();
};

$scope.fetchData = function(){
    $http.get('index').success(function(data){
         console.log(data);
        $scope.namesData = data;
    });
};
```

This is the HTML code

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="name in namesData">
   <td><span>{{name.first_name}}</span></td>
   <td><span>{{name.last_name}}</span></td>
```

Totally seven records in the database, it displays seven blank space. Not visible in JSON data in HTML.

Comment: The [`.success` method is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Comment: Post the result of  `console.log(data);`

Comment: {id: 0, firstname: "John", lastname: "Smith", $$hashKey: "object:6"}
1: {id: 0, firstname: "Moore", lastname: "David", $$hashKey: "object:7"}
2: {id: 0, firstname: "Peter", lastname: "Parker", $$hashKey: "object:8"}
3: {id: 0, firstname: "Guadalupe", lastname: "Bolan", $$hashKey: "object:9"}
4: {id: 0, firstname: "Austin", lastname: "Miller", $$hashKey: "object:10"}
5: {id: 0, firstname: "Steave", lastname: "Smith", $$hashKey: "object:11"}
6: {id: 0, firstname: "vignesh", lastname: "waran", $$hashKey: "object:12"}
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties in your json are `firstname` and `lastname` but in your html, you're displaying `first_name`, `last_name`, you should do something like this :

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="name in namesData">
   <td><span>{{name.firstname}}</span></td>
   <td><span>{{name.lastname}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gladiatoriitoo/L6fk431x/6/)

Comment: thank you very much, it works. I created a table in this format create table(first_name varchar(10), last_name varchar(10));  But JSON data retrieve from same variable like first_name, last_name.  I don't know how came like firstname, lastname

Comment: the json is a representation of your entity, which doesn't have underscores i guess, and no `@JsonProperty` annotation, right ?